# Entity Framework 4.1 Implement INotifyPropertyChanged for POCO objects

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

I am implementing code first, MVC pattern and using Entity Framework 4.1. I put my problems in bold.

Lets assume (for simplify) that I have the following POCO object (Department) and I would like to know when it changes once contextDB.SaveChanges() is carried on and update it, so I implement the following:

```
public class Department : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    [Key(), Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    private string name;

    [Required]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.name== value)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.name= value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    private string personInCharge;

    [Required]
    public string PersonInCharge
    {
        get
        {
            return this.personInCharge;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.personInCharge== value)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.personInCharge= value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(this, 
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PersonInCharge"));
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 projects(class libraries), for M(Model), V(View) and C(Controller).

From view(V), user generates and event, for example, adding a departament by pressing a button so the View which references the Controller(C), calls a method "Add" in the controller.

The controller(C) which references the Model(M), has access to the context because it instantiates the class which derives from dbContext in the Model, and through the context updates the entity "Department" by doing for example dbContext.departments.add(newDepartment).

When entity departments is updated in the model, NotifyPropertyChanged described above in the entity Department is raised but my problem starts here and is: **how to say to the View, hey! entity departments has changed so view departments should be updated!**

To achieve it, I have implemented observer pattern, I mean the view department which has a method called "Update", is attached to a collection of observers maintained by the model so the model, on a property change, iterates over this collection and call method "Update" for each view and the view updates.

My problem here is: **I do not know how to subscribe to event PropertyChanged in the above class department from the view in order to once a property is changed in Department POCO object (class describe above), the model iterates over the observer collection that contains the observers attached and then calls the appropriate "Update" method for each view(observer) attached to the collection. or maybe it there another better way to do it rather than using INotifyPropertyChanged for POCO objects?**

Also I see a problem of using INotifyPropertyChanged, I mean, for example, each time a depatment is added, the view will be updated twice as NotifyPropertyChanged is raised twice, one from Name property and another from PersonInCharge property. Another problem here: **How to raise only one time the NotifyPropertyChanged event instead of twice?**